# Dagger injects {} method issue

Tags: android, code-injection, dagger

I would like to know

> why we need to add

```
injects = { 
            FirstFragment.class, 
            DownloadManager.class,
            BookRefreshTask.class 
        }
```

***in application class or module class.***

as we injecting the fragment and activity using `graph.inject(this)` method

Comment: In short, Dagger needs to know where to start injecting. The classes in that t=list are things that are themselves _not_ injected, but which have injected members.

Comment: @Karakuri start injecting is known from where we write graph add method which is in application class.

but i want to know what is the use of injects  {} annotation i mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

As I undestand this.

Dagger consists of two modules:

- runtime module (which uses @Inject annotations to satisfy dependencies at runtime)
- compile time module (which uses "injects = {A1.class, A2.class}" to check code for unsatisfied dependencies).

So this is a price we need to pay for compile time errors handling.